# Arranging connected boxes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to draw a diagram similar tp this one:

[image: desired]

What I currently have is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\tikzstyle{atomic} = [draw, thick,minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=1.5cm]
\tikzstyle{io} = [draw, thick,circle]
\node (a) at (4,2) [atomic] {A};
\node (b) at (6,2) [atomic] {B};
\node[io] (zb) at (5,2){$Z_B$};
\draw[-latex,thick](a)
edge 
node[pos=0,above left]{$Y_A$}
(zb);

\draw[-latex,thick]
(zb)
edge
node[pos=1,above right]{$X_B$}
(b);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: current]

Is there a simpler way to arrange the boxes and circles?
Currently I try to find the correct coordinates manually.

How can I have the arrows make the 90 degree turns?
How can I nest the smaller boxes into the big one and annotated the entry and exit arrows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:
[image]

Code in pure TikZ:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz,preview]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,%
                    backgrounds,%
                    calc,%
                    fit,%
                    positioning,
                    scopes,shadows}

\makeatletter
\def\tikzsavelastnodename#1{\let#1=\tikz@last@fig@name}
\makeatother

    \begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            > = {Triangle[]},
node distance = 2mm and 7mm,
% for labels inside node shape
inlabel/.style args =
    {#1:#2}{append after command=
            {node[inner sep=1mm,anchor=#1] at (\tikzsavednodename.#1) {#2}}
            },
% schemas' blocks
        atomic/.style = {draw, thick, fill=white, 
                         minimum size=1.5cm, drop shadow,
                         append after command= {\pgfextra{\tikzsavelastnodename\tikzsavednodename}},#1
                        },
            io/.style = {draw, thick, fill=white, circle, drop shadow},
                    ]
%---
\node[atomic,
      inlabel=west:$X_A$,
      inlabel=east:$Y_A$,
      inlabel=south:$A$,
      ]                         (a)     {};
\node[io,below right=of a.south east]   (zn)    {$Z_N$};
\node[atomic,
      inlabel=west:$X_A$,
      inlabel=east:$Y_A$,
      inlabel=south:$B$,
      below left=of zn]         (b)     {};
\node[io, left=of a]            (za)    {$Z_A$};
\node[io, left=of b]            (zb)    {$Z_B$};
%
\coordinate[left=of za.150]     (xn');
\coordinate[left=of xn']        (xn);
\coordinate[left=4mm of zn.150] (zn');
\coordinate[right=of zn]        (yn);
% lines connecting block A
\draw[->] (xn) node[left] {$X_N$} -- (za.150);
\draw[->] (za) edge (a);
\draw[->] (a.east) -| (zn') -| (xn' |- za.210) -- (za.210);
\draw[->] (zn') -- (zn.150); 
% lines connecting block B
\draw[->] (zb) -- (b);
\draw[->] (b)  -| (zn' |- zn.210) -- (zn.210);
\draw[->] (xn' |- zn') |- (zb);
\draw[->] (zn) -- (yn) node[right] {$Y_N$};
% outer block (N)
\scoped[on background layer]
    \node[atomic,inner xsep=0mm,
          fit=(xn) (a) (yn) (b),
          inlabel=south west:$N$] {};
        \end{tikzpicture}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \end{document}
```

For drawing lines I explicit defined a set of coordinates. Fro 90 degree turn exist syntax `|-` and `-|`. As can you see in MWE, both I used extensively used in above code for drawing of lines as well for determined some impliticit determined coordinated (for example `(xn' |- zn')` for start of line to node `zb`.

Comment: Looks great! What does the syntax `za.210` mean?

Comment: @m.s., `za` is name of node, number `210` is angle of straight line through shape center point. On cross of it with shape border is point -- anchor -- to which someone like to draw a line or star with it drawing.

Comment: @m.s. an addendum to previous comment: ``za.0` is equivalent to `za.east`, `za.45` is equivalent for `za.north east` etc. With other words,  angles `0, 45, 90, 135, 180 225, 270` and `315` define the same points on shape border as `east˛ `north east`, north`, `north west` etc extensions to node names.

Comment: Do you know where I can find this in the Tikz manual?

Comment: See examples in shape libraries (chapter 67, pp. 683 in my CVS version of manual). Well, there this not explained on such a way as I do in comment above, but you can easy figured out the idea. Unfortunately, the TikZ manual is really huge in it is easy to lost in it.